# Swift SKPhysics Node flying without resistance

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skphysicsworld

I want a node to fly and behave like it has no resistance. I thought I can make the node "massless" and "frictionless" so that I can apply an Impulse and the node will never stop flying around.

```
physicsBody?.allowsRotation     =   false  
physicsBody?.isDynamic          =   true  
physicsBody?.affectedByGravity  =   false  
physicsBody?.mass               =   0  
physicsBody?.linearDamping      =   1  
physicsBody?.restitution        =   1  
physicsBody?.angularDamping     =   0  
physicsBody?.angularVelocity    =   1  
physicsBody?.density            =   0  
physicsBody?.friction           =   0
```

As I saw that the node flies longer but will stop nevertheless, I applied an Impulse to the node permanently with the update function (what I hope to avoid in the end solution).
The problem now is, that after the first collision the node hasn't the right orientation to rebound rightly at the next collisions. And if I allow the node to rotate, the node will rotate wildly...

[Thats the Node(s) how I want them to behave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPfTz.gif)

Comment: What happens if you give it a small mass? There might be an issue with 0 (because all physics calculations should get unrealistic results).

Comment: Why would you not give it a mass?  If you have no gravity, damping, or friction, it should be flying forever

Comment: ...you have gravity apparently